# Displaying data from SQL server on UI or on browser

Tags: sql-server, database, user-interface

I am working on an application wherein data flows in the form of trades in SQL server. We have different tables and the data flows down from one table to other every day.

I want to develop a kind of UI wherein the daily summary of inflow of data into the database should be shown on a browser. (may be on local hose 8080?)
I am a QA and don't have development experience, it would be great if anyone can let me know simplest way to do this?

Comment: By summary, do you mean how many records were created/updated/deleted?

Comment: yeah, you can call it as a daily summary. How many trades received, how many went to next table or how many failed in current table etc

Comment: I suggest you start with Power BI

Comment: I do not know how your database is set is up so cannot provide a complete solution. I would however recommend you to take a look at SQL Server Reporting services. You can create a report which executes required SQL query and displays data in table or graphical format. You can also view this report in browser.

Comment: I can provide you brief database setup if you want any specifics?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid might cost extra money if they do not have it yet.

Comment: Power BI Desktop is free. Licencing models for any reporting tool are complicated and there are no clues in the question as to the requirements.

Comment: @NitQA event then, you will need to identify the requirements and write query accordingly. It would be a simple one with date comparison and status checks. Have a go at it yourself!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Ah right. My mind went straight to on cloud set up

Comment: Just to clarify, there are no requirements as such to have a graphical representation of database data, i want to do it myself as an add on.

Comment: Lets take this example, lets say i have three tables A, B and C which may have any columns. I want to display table A processed 100 trades today, B may be 50 and C may be 15. This data i want to display on UI depending on timestamp.

Comment: An add on to what? You want to do it yourself but you have no dev experience and for some reason you don't want to use an easy free tool like Power BI.  This is why these kind's of questions are off topic because we could be here forever trying to isolate your requirements.

Comment: Sure Nick, i will have a look into power BI to check whether i can use it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create functions or stored procedures to collect these for you; there's no tool in SQL that will automagically know what you want to see.

Identify the data you want, write the functions or stored procedures, then use a simple solution like Entity Framwork and ASP to display it.